# Emulate FCM token update for debugging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to emulate update of Firebase cloud messaging token?
Any console command in AndroidStudio/Firebase or something else?
I need the method `onNewToken(token)` in my `FirebaseMessagingService` to be called when the app is not launched. I can't just wait until it's called on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Flow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=vi#sample-register), you should go to app settings for your app and clear data `onNewToken` should be called

> The registration token may change when: The app deletes Instance ID,The app is restored on a new device, The user uninstalls/reinstall the app, The user clears app data.